# Feynman diagrams of partonic processes

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

Are partonic processes (as for example b -> s$\gamma$) representable by Feynman diagrams in the Standard model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard model Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model) covers all elementary particle interactions in [the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg). The whole model is within quantum field theory, and if quantum number and  general conservation laws allow for a diagram, it can be written and calculated.

For a review of diagrams have a [look here.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9512395.pdf)

Comment: so how would this diagram be?

Comment: did you look at the last link I gave? diagram c will give a photon +others. b) is not allowed according to the write up , the GIM mechanism suppresses fig 1b). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIM_mechanism